# Will my travel history in Africa and Uzbekistan affect my ability to get a US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, nigerian-citizens

I have traveled to several nations namely :

- Rwanda
- Togo
- Benin Rep
- Cameroon
- Uzbekistan

I have a job at a US firm: my salary is $3000 / month and I work remotely.

Is this a good standing to get a United States tourist visa at this point?

Comment: Working remotely for a US firm? Good luck with that.

Comment: You can't possibly work for a US firm remotely. You might be a _contractor_ but you can't _work_ for them. You need to sort this out with yourself.

Comment: Have you seen the movie Borat?  In it, all the world's troubles are blamed on Uzbeks...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine I think it was about Kazakhstan, or did I miss the part two?

Comment: Why not get your employer to bring you stateside for a couple of weeks to visit their head office, attend a conference, etc ?

Comment: Can you confirm exactly who/where you work for? 

 i.e. I work 'for' a US firm in the sense that the HQ is located in the US, but my actual employer (i.e. as per my pay cheques, tax responsibilities, etc) is the local/subsidiary HQ situated in my country of residence.  

This has applied all three times I've worked for US-headquartered organizations.

Comment: @Dmitry Borat's character was Kazakh but never missed an opportunity to blame Uzbekistan for everything. It was a running joke in the first movie. Also, Lily from AT&T is Uzbek.

Answer (score 23):

Your chances to get a US tourism visa is a matter of opinion, and opinions are off-topic for this site. Still, two aspects of your application are troublesome; both suggest that your application for a US tourism visa will not be approved.

First, your travel history is mostly to close-by (Uzbekistan is the exception) and easier-to-enter countries. The visa examiner won't be impressed by this travel history. Your travel history would be improved if you show travel to (and return from) countries where entry difficulty is mid-level: Turkey, South Africa, Singapore, Thailand, et al. What would really impress is travel to (and timely return from) a country or countries that are hard to enter: the UK, Canada, Ireland, a country in the EU, Australia, New Zealand.

Second, having a remote US job, as @littleadv correctly points out in comments, is a big problem. Remember that US immigration law requires the visa examiner to presume that you intend to immigrate to the US and remain in the US; it is up to the applicant to disprove that presumption. Having a US employer provides motivation to stay in the US, not to return to your home country after the trip.

In other words, a remote US job doesn't provide a home-country tie. Home-country ties are things that suggest you'll want to return to Nigeria after your trip. Close family, children, property, a good job in the home country all would make your application more appealing.

Comment: Ah, i think i get it now. in the space of Midlevel, Does Morocco fall in this place? I plan on visiting Morocco and staying a week. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Perhaps it does. Morocco requires visiting Nigerians to apply for and receive a visa, so there's at least some obstacles in traveling there. Good luck!

Comment: If, on the other hand, OP is actually working for a Nigerian subsidiary of a US firm (probably more likely than "working for a US firm remotely"), that in my opinion would be a positive. Not only do they have a job to return to in Nigeria, but they have a legitimate business reason to visit the US.

Comment: @abligh: would "legitimate business reasons" really count towards a tourist visa? (Honest question, I'm not familiar with the distinctions and limitations in the non-VWP/ESTA case.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Some "business activities" can legally be done by travelers entering on a US tourist visa. However, the distinction between "permitted" and "not permitted" is challenging to parse; using the wrong word or phrase or concept to the CBP officer can easily result in a refusal of entry.